# SSRS 2005 display seconds in HH:MM:SS for durations greater than 24 hours

Tags: vb.net, timestamp, ssrs-2008, reportingservices-2005, reporting-services

First off, thank you to everyone for your help!!!

All I'm trying to do is get some VB.net code that works in SSRS 2005 to display 123465 as 34:17:45.

This is what I've tried so far:

```
Public Shared Function secondsToString(seconds As int64) As String
Dim myTS As New TimeSpan(seconds * 10000000)
If seconds > 0 then
  Return String.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}:{2:00}",myTS.Hours, myTS.Minutes, myTS.Seconds)
Else
  Return ""
End if
End Function
```

Any help you can provide would be great!

Thanks again!

Comment: added in the question, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Public Shared Function secondsToString(seconds As int64) As String
Dim myTS as new TimeSpan(seconds * 10000000)
If seconds > 0 then
  Return String.Format("{0:HH\\:mm\\:ss}",seconds)
Else
  Return ""
End if
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks! but that doesn't seem to work. It says that the cast to a TimeSpan is invalid.

Answer (score 1):

```
Public Shared Function secondsToString(seconds As int64) As String
   Dim myTS As New TimeSpan(seconds * 10000000)
   If seconds > 0 then
     Return String.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}",myTS.TotalHours, myTS.Minutes)
   Else
     Return ""
   End if
End Function
```